# Pagination links not displaying all pages

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to read data from the WordPress database table and display it on my website. This is my pagination script and I am able to get all the data. The limit and number of rows per page are all fine. When I change pages, I still see the first page but the url changes. Please how do I handle this? Thank you

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$er = $wpdb->show_errors();
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM koh_user");

// number of rows to show per page
$rowsperpage = 10;

// find out how many rows are in the table 
$numrows = $wpdb->num_rows;

// find out total pages
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

// get the current page or set a default
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
   // cast var as int
   $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
} else {
   // default page num
   $page = 1;
} 

// the offset of the list, based on current page 
$offset = ($page - 1) * $rowsperpage;

// get the info from the db 
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT CONCAT( koh_user.fname, '  ', koh_user.lname) as name, koh_user.id as id, koh_user.username as username from koh_user LIMIT $rowsperpage OFFSET $offset
");

// Display the rows 
echo "<style>";
echo "body {font-family: Arial;}";
echo ".table_container { padding: 10px 12px 0px 12px;  border: 1px solid #ccc;  }";
echo ".table_container th { background-color:lightblue; color:black; font-weight:bold; border-left: 1px solid white;}";
echo "</style></head>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<div class=\"table_container\"><table>";
echo "<tr><th style=\"padding-left:10px;\">Nom</th><th>Nom d'utilisateur</th><th>Role</th><th></th></tr>";

foreach ($result as $row) {
echo "<tr class ='info'>
<td>" . $row->name . "</td>
<td>" . $row->username . "</td>
<td>" . $row->role . "</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>"
;}
echo "</table></div>";

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
// range of num links to show
$range = 3;

// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($page > 1) {
   // show << link to go back to page 1
   echo " <a href='/?page_id=347?page=1'><<</a>  ";
   // get previous page num
   $prevpage = $page - 1;
   // show < link to go back to 1 page
   echo " <a href='/?page_id=347?page=$prevpage'><</a>  ";
} // end if 

// loop to show links to range of pages around  page
for ($x = ($page - $range); $x < (($page + $range) + 1); $x++) {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
      // if we're on  page...
      if ($x == $page) {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
      // if not current page...
      } else {
         // make it a link
         echo " <a href='/?page_id=347?page=$x'>$x</a>  ";
      } // end else
   } // end if 
} // end for

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
if ($page != $totalpages) {
   // get next page
   $nextpage = $page + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page 
   echo " <a href='/?page_id=347?page=$nextpage'>></a>  ";
   // echo forward link for lastpage
   echo " <a href='/?page_id=347?page=$totalpages'>>></a>  ";
} // end if

?>
```

Comment: Is that the actual code? There are two forward slashes (//) in your SQL that make it invalid.

Comment: At the top you have a `$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM koh_user");` but then you never use that value because `$result` is overwritten later.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you for your comment. This is the actual code. the first `$result` is used when i call `$numrows = $wpdb->num_rows;`, Nevertheless I have tried renaming the second one but  no changes.

Comment: Yeah I don't know. I would put the entire `SELECT...` in a variable and echo it before executing to see if it changes and then execute that same SELECT to in phpMyAdmin to see if the results are different. Then you'll know whether the issue is there or with the code below it.

Comment: @AaronJ, I have tried that but its not working. When I run the select query in phpmyadmin, it outputs exactly what I want. I am wondering if should not run a for loop on a page number.